# How Can we change the Value of Menu with its selected submenu, for client site.?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, menu, submenu

I want to change the value of Menu item with its selected submenu. I've done this using JS first. But it is again set to Menu value on loading the page.

Is there any way to do change the value of Menu for the current Session.

I'll be very grateful if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: paste your code here, what you tried

Comment: You are going to need to edit your question, showing both the php code that generates the menu, and the existing javascript that makes the change

Comment: Please have a look on what is meant by [MCVE]. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You for your answers, now I have found the answer and this is something like this:

```
<div class="container">
```

### Dropdowns

The .dropdown class is used to indicate a dropdown menu.

Use the .dropdown-menu class to actually build the dropdown menu.

To open the dropdown menu, use a button or a link with a class of .dropdown-toggle and data-toggle="dropdown".

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><?php echo $page[basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])] ?>
<span class="caret"></span></button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<?php 
$page=array('index.php'=>'Home','html.php'=>'Html','css.php'=>'CSS','javascript.php'=>'Javascript');
unset($page[basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])]);
foreach ($page as $key => $value) {
  ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></a></li>
  <?php
}
 ?>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have no code pasted to adjust the code to your needs i can only show you how the `sessionStorage` of JavaScript works. W3schools has [an example and explanation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). If the page is not working you can check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raq3tvuv/).

The sessionStorage object is equal to the localStorage object, except that it stores the data for only one session. The data is deleted when the user closes the specific browser tab.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function clickCounter() {
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
        sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount)+1;
    } else {
        sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
} else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter is reset.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ty for your help... I'll try it